# Parametric or non-parametric test?

Tags: nonparametric

In outline shape analysis after getting the results of chain code (in shape software) and principal component values  should I use the parametric (ANOVA) or non parametric (Kruskal-Wallis) test to evaluate the variation between populations ($n=40$)?